# Creating a mesh object problem

Tags: mesh

Hi everybody I am a newbie! While I was working on Blender I added a uv sphere object and since I know it should be created in its default form ( I mean eg: adding a uv sphere segments:32 size:1 etc etc) but when I clicked on it to add it, it was added in a form that I last added a uv sphere. How can I revert my original uv sphere addition form back? I don"t know maybe I accidentally clicked on smt.. but I don"t really know. And Now I checked that this problem occurs in every blender file I am working.. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, if you close and restart Blender all operator presets should be reset to default values, but if you don't want to do that you can reset them one by one by hand.

Just add a new UV Sphere or invoke any other operator, and from the *3D View Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd> key) you can reset any property to default value by right-clicking it and choosing *Reset to Default Value*

[image]

Comment: Hello there! Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.  I tried your 2nd way and it worked' but after that I restarted my pc and operated blender again I created a mesh object and changed its segments size etc at the beginning and after that I created a second one (expecting a default one) no again the same thing (it duplicated the previous one), your way saves the day but before that it never happened and I dont know how to get rid of this :(

Comment: This has always been the default behavior, Blender always saves the last used operator settings for the current session, until you restart Blender or open a new instance.

Comment: omg was it default? Please check me if I really understood once you add a mesh  object you change its size segments scale initially while adding and add it. After this stage if you want to add another mesh from the same group, once you created it, it always carries the previously created objects initially added properties.

Comment: Yes, that's right, this has always been the default behavior of Blender. If you add some object then add another of the same type afterwards, it will initially carry the same properties. This is also true for all other operators, if you execute a certain command, by default the second try will have the previous values pre-filled.